# oAuth on NodeJs for Tumblr using Express

Tags: node.js, oauth, express

I try to connect to **tumblr** with oauth of NodeJs using Express Framework but i always have this  message **oauth_timestamp is too far away; we believe it is now 1362603519, you sent 1362599755, 3764 seconds away**

Please Help Me

Comment: showing your current relevant code is usually helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offhand it looks like a timezone issue; are you not converting the current time to UTC before making your request?

Comment: var oa = new OAuth(
  'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token',
  'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token',
  config.consumer_key,
  config.secret_key,
  '1.0A',
  'http://localhost:3000/callback',
  'HMAC-SHA1'
);

Comment: And this is my function 
function getOAuthAccessToken(req, res, oauth_verifier) {
  oa.getOAuthAccessToken(
    req.session.oauth.oauth_token,
    req.session.oauth.oauth_token_secret,
    oauth_verifier,
    function(err, oauth_access_token, oauth_access_token_secret, results) {
      if(err) {
        res.send(err, 500);
        return;
      }
      req.session.oauth = {
        access_token: oauth_access_token,
        access_token_secret: oauth_access_token_secret
      };
      res.redirect('/dashb');
    }
  );
}